# Русские окончания в иноязычных словах

Tags: заимствования, окончания, латиница-кириллица, апостроф

Пример:

> Воспользуйтесь этим beautifier'ом.

В русскоязычных авторитетных источниках мне не встречался термин `бьютифаер` или какой-либо другой, записанный русскими буквами, характеризующий данную разновидность программ. Вопросы:

- Корректен ли пример? А `Воспользуйтесь этим beautifier`?
- Если сливать русское окончание с иноязычной основой допустимо, то должны ли стоять между основой и окончанием какие-либо знаки препинания?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Для разговорной речи правильным будет "воспользуйтесь этим beautifier'ом".

> Корректен ли пример?

Да.

> А Воспользуйтесь этим beautifier?

Нет. Идея не склонять то, что непонятно или написано "чужими" буквами - это отнюдь не здорово. Идет, видимо, от английского влияния, из рекламы, когда название товара надо произнести четко и так, чтоб без сомнений в исходной форме.

А историческая тенденция к склонению всего, что только можно склонять - вот это действительно основополагающий принцип русского языка.

> Если сливать русское окончание с иноязычной основой допустимо, то 
>   должны ли стоять между основой и окончанием какие-либо знаки 
>   препинания?

Да, апостроф, как вы и написали. Традиция многовековая, так записывали начинающие осваиваться языком иностранные (особенно французские) слова с середины XVIII века.

В книжных и официальных текстах этого, понятно, следует избегать, но в разговорном стиле - тут сомнений нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо сомнительного пути приделывания русского окончания к непереведённому слову в латинице (такой вариант всегда уязвим для критики, независимо от того, найдётся ли в каком-нибудь источнике попытка его оправдания) есть простые возможности.

1. Если вы пишете авторский текст, можно добавить к слову в латинице видовое наименование того, к чему оно относится - тогда достаточно будет склонять это наименование (условно говоря, "**воспользуйтесь прибором/средством Beautifier**").

Этот вариант (с написанием английского слова в латинице) уместен в случае, когда слово не вызывает разночтений у публики, которой тест адресован. В противном случае, особенно, если текст предназначен для прочтения вслух, возможны неловкие ситуации в духе одного известного чиновника. Например, только что в передаче "Своя игра" участники-эрудиты именно в таком духе обсуждали с ведущим название фильма Хичкока. Вместо известного русского прокатного названия "Психоз" они зачем-то пытались произнести английское название фильма (Psycho, "Психопат") как "психо", что очень далеко от английского произношения (примерно "сайкоу") и сразу проявляет смутность познаний эрудитов в элементах данного языка.

2. Новое слово, не имеющее русского аналога, можно подвергнуть формальной транскрипции в кириллицу (по правилам англо-русской практической транскрипции, как часто поступают с названиями фирм) и уже тогда склонять, если форма слова позволяет. В этом случае слово заключают в кавычки. Такой вариант записи разумен и в случае передачи чьей-то устной речи, когда человек уже применил новое слово со склонением (**воспользуйтесь "бьютифаером"**): кавычки при нём будут означать условность такого названия (слово подобрано к случаю, это не общепринятое понятие).

Comment: Ваше мнение по поводу «бьютифаера» понял. Спасибо! // Оффтоп о «Психо» («Психозе»): я многократный участник упомянутой Вами передачи — доводилось слышать всякие ляпы, но именно по данному случаю не считаю, что игроки и ведущий были неправы. // **1)** > известного русского прокатного названия "Психоз" — В России фильм официально чаще издавался как «Психо». См. итог [**обсуждения**](http://bit.ly/PsychoFilmRename). // **2)** > зачем-то пытались произнести английское название фильма — я не вправе утверждать, о чём думали знатоки и ведущий, ...

Comment: ... но вероятнее всего они пытались произнести не «английское», а наиболее часто встречающееся название фильма. // **3)** Почему мы должны произносить название фильма именно так, как это делается в английском языке, а не так, как фильм известен в русскоязычных источниках? Есть ли какие-то языковые нормы на сей счёт? // я не сомневаюсь в Вашей компетентности и допускаю, что Вашу точку зрения насчёт названия фильма поддержат другие профессиональные лингвисты. Однако **а)** Случай не столь очевидный, чтобы можно было утверждать о «смутности познаний эрудитов», ...

Comment: ... **б)** Не считаю репрезентативным и, соответственно, правильным делать вывод об общем качестве познаний предмета на основании одного-единственного прецедента, каким бы ошибочным он ни был. // Спасибо.

Comment: Я не знал, что были издания под таким названием. Под названием "Психоз" (задолго до тиражирования дисков) фильм не раз демонстрировался по телевидению и обсуждался кинокритикой. Но теперь, по крайней мере, понятно, откуда это возникло в обсуждении. Проблема такого перевода в том, что нет русского слова "психо", это приставка.

Comment: Что касается языковых ляпов а передаче, то они случались и в вопросах, например, некорректен вопрос, который звучал примерно так: "какой цвет, обозначаемый иероглифом цин некто имел в виду?" Известно, что нельзя назвать иероглиф по его произношению (здесь "цин"): этому произношению обычно соответствует не один десяток иероглифов с разными значениями. Так что прецедент был.